# Windows batch compare string with spaces

Tags: batch-file

I am a programmer but am new to Windows batch scripting.
I need to check if a certain substring is present in a variable created using `Delayed Expansion`.
The problem is that the substring contains spaces and for the life of me I can't figure out how to properly handle them. Online everyone says what I tried myself, just use quotes. But when I do it never finds a match, obviously something is wrong.
This is the relevant part of the code:

```
IF !printer:~0^,9!=="Test Comp" (
    call :SetPrinter !printer!
) ELSE (
    ECHO Not TestComp: !printer!
)
```

When I try comparing only 'Test' (and ofc 4 characters) and remove the quotes, it always works. The quotes themselves seem to mess things up. I also tried putting quotes around the entire if condition as I saw similar stuff online, but that too did not work.
As what I'm trying to do here should be relatively simple, can you please provide me a IF statement that properly handles spaces?

Comment: Remove the caret. Enclose **both** sides of the comparison in quotes - the match is literal. If there may be a case difference, use `if /i`

Comment: `IF "!printer:~0,9!" == "Test Comp" (`

Comment: @Aacini I did exactly that too (should have mentioned) and it did not work as expected either. Ill try what i can do

Comment: What "did not work as expected" exactly means? Please, put an `echo "!printer:~0,9!"` command before the `if`. If the echo shows `"Test Comp"` and the `if`is *NOT* executed, REPORT IT!!!  PS - I assumed that your code have a `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning...

Comment: @Aacini I indeed used `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. My mistake was not removing the carret when i tried this solution. Bc the mistake was twofold i couldnt figure out the solution. Gonna read through the answer provided by @Mofi to understand this stuff better. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, I suggested to use `IF "!printer:~0,9!" == "Test Comp" (` and your answer was: _"I did **exactly** that too and it did not work as expected"_. In cases like this, we couldn't help any further...  **`;(`**

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Magoo and Aacini in the comments, my mistake was twofold. I was using an unneeded caret and the quotes needed to be around both sides. This code works perfectly:

```
IF "!printer:~0,9!"=="Test Comp" (
    call :SetPrinter !printer!
) ELSE (
    ECHO Not TestComp: !printer!
)
```

Hope this might be helpful to anyone else new to BATCH scripting.